# Mock Method of authowired bean using mockito and spring mock

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing

I have to impelement a test for MyService that conntain two methods method1 & method2:

and the method1 call method2 (method1 --> method2 )

so i've somthing like this in my test class

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = SpringBootApplicationTest.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { conf.class })
public class CommonCAMServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    private MyService myService;

     test_method_1(){...}// this is what i want to implement and i have to mock the method2 call
     test_method_2(){...}//this work fine


...
```

so i want to test my method1 but with the mock of method ( even my service class is autowired not mocked)

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Mockito supports what I will call "partial mocking";
it is called Spy.

Instead of creating a mock bean for your service,
create a Spy.
Also,
as mentioned in other answers,
don't user `@Autowire` for the service.

Here is some example code:

```
public class CommonCAMServiceTest
{
    @Spy
    private MyService myService;

    @Before
    public void before()
    {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

        // Mock method2 for every test.
        doReturn(something).when(myService).method2();
    }

    @Test
    public void someTestName()
    {
        // Mock method2 in this test.
        doReturn(somethingElse).when(myService).method2();

        ... call method1 to do stuff.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you this in case you use MockitoJunitRunner in my case i use SpringRunner so i've do the same thing but with the spring annotation @SpyBean
Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Create two Services for those two Methods. Then you can mock one service to test the other.

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume that your `Service` look like that:

```
@Service
public class MyService {
    public void method1() {
        method2();
    }

    public void method2() {
        System.out.println("calling method 2");
    }
}
```

So if you willing to Mock the method2 function you we'll need to use a Mocked Bean for that using Spring & Mockito

```
@MockBean // Use that instead of @Autowired, will create a Mocked Bean
public MyService service;

@Test
public void testing() {
    Mockito.doAnswer((Answer<Void>) invocation -> {
        System.out.println("mocked");

        return null;
    }).when(service).method2();


    Mockito.doCallRealMethod().when(service).method1();

    service.method1();
}
```

Comment: Thank you i think tha could work in same case, but in my case it doesn't work cause i have an autowired field inside my service when i call method1 i need this field to be instantiated by the real value 
so when you use mockBean the field value is null